# Change figures list name and Include graphics into arabic text

Tags: table-of-contents, arabic, figure-placement

- I want to change the figures list name from "قائمة الأشكال" to "قائمة الصور"
- When I try to include graphics (pdf, eps) into arabic text, the figure in the resulted pdf is always hidden in the right of the page !!
- How can I change sections numerals from Hindi to Arabic without using polyglossia?
- How to align all page numbers in TOC to the right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=23mm,bottom=22mm,left=2cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\addto\captionsarabic{%
\renewcommand\chaptername{الفصل}
}
\addto{\captionsarabic}{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{قائمة المحتويات}}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures


\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}

\chapter{الأول}

\section{الأول}

\subsection{الأول}

\subsection{الثاني}

\section{الثاني}

\subsection{الأول}

\subsection{الثاني}

\subsection{الثالث}

\section{الثالث}

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is there any reasons you are loading both `arabtex` and `babel`? When you say without `polyglossia`, do you actually mean with `pdftex` and not with `xetex` or `luatex`? (Note `babel` supports Arabic in the three engines.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example with some changes follows (with a few comments). WRT to `\includegraphics`, see [figure using Babel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387388/figure-using-babel). Mixing directions with `pdftex` requires a lot of hard work, so consider switching to `xetex` or `luatex` (see [Arabic - Babel](https://latex3.github.io/babel/guides/locale-arabic.html)).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=23mm,bottom=22mm,left=2cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LFE,LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 

% Although there are a few alternatives, this is the
% canonical way to redefine captions:

\setlocalecaption{arabic}{chapter}{الفصل}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{contents}{قائمة المحتويات}
\setlocalecaption{arabic}{listfigure}{قائمة الصور}

% The font encoding must be switched to get Latin characters:

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thepart
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\@Roman\c@part}}
\renewcommand\thechapter
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\@arabic\c@chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}}
\renewcommand\thefigure
  {{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\ifnum\c@chapter>\z@\thechapter.\fi\@arabic\c@figure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\selectlanguage{arabic}

\chapter{الأول}

\begin{figure}
\caption{شكل}
\foreignlanguage{english}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a.png}}
\end{figure}

\section{الأول}

\subsection{الأول}

\subsection{الثاني}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer. One thing if you may, how can change figures numeral to arabic numbers?

Comment: @DaouhaPoetry I’ve edited the code to add `\thefigure`.